# Should rviz have a segmentation fault with other nodes are stopped? e.g. openni_camera launch

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, openni-node, nvidia

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm using diamondback and rviz has segmentation faults often whenever I kill another node.

Should I expect this whenever stopping a node that was publishing a topic that rviz is subscribed to?

E.g.: I run roscore in one terminal, openni_camera openni_node.launch, and rviz from another terminal.  I can view the /camera/rgb/points topic in rviz fine.  However, if I stop the openni_node.launch, rviz segfaults.

Is there anything I can do to change the rosrun / roslaunch settings to prevent this?  It would be helpful to not have to restart rviz everytime I want to stop a node to debug something.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9556/should-rviz-have-a-segmentation-fault-with-other-nodes-are-stopped?-e.g.-openni_camera-launch/) by [elsey](https://answers.ros.org/users/347/elsey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-03-24

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-24**:
Could you make sure to include which version of Ubuntu you are running on and what video drivers? There is a known bug with certain versions of Nvidia drivers on 10.10 that causes anything linked against OpenGL to crash. See https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20110204.151901.a4e1d645.en.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks, Eric, for pointing out the thread on the drivers issue.

I upgraded drivers from NVIDIA 260.19.06 to NVIDIA 260.19.44, and that solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [elsey](https://answers.ros.org/users/347/elsey/) with karma: 76 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-04-02**:
I can confirm that the launchpad approach also works to fix this issue.

**Comment by [elsey](https://answers.ros.org/users/347/elsey/) on 2011-03-30**:
I updated by downloading and installing the driver from the Nvidia website: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us .  Someone also pointed me to [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) as an alternative to installing from the website, but I haven't tried it myself.

**Comment by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on 2011-03-29**:
Can you explain how you updated the Nvidia driver to 260.19.44? Did you download it from their site, or update something that made Ubuntu pull in the newest driver?